# .NET Embedding application in windows-taskbar

Tags: c#, .net, windows-vista, windows-xp

We've all seen it and now I want to do it.  How may I go about achieving this effect with a winforms application?

[image]
<sub>(source: [activewin.com](http://www.activewin.com/winvista/images/Windows%20Media%20Player%20-%20Taskbar%20Player.png))</sub>

Comment: @Peter: What version of Windows are you talking about here, looking at your screenshot it looks and resembles Windows 7 feature..can you clarify?

Comment: This is vista, but I've seen it also implemented in XP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably going to want to start reading about [Desk Bands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776819%28VS.85%29.aspx#desk_bands). It's not an easy process, and you won't be able to just put your winforms application in the task bar. It also depends on what version of Windows you want to target, as tommieb75 pointed out, the newer versions of windows have better integrating capabilities.

In addition to the above, the [Windows v6.1 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms716696.aspx) includes a desk band example that you could check out.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article on how to use the new Windows 7 features in C# [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/Windows7APICodePack.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/W7ProgressAndOverlay.aspx).

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: this is not a windows 7 specific feature though

Comment: @Joachim: Thanks for the heads up! :) After I put my comment into the question, and during editing, the tags were added to indicate vista.. sorry...

Comment: Sorry! I put them in because of this comment :)

Comment: Actually, some of the API used is compatible with Vista...http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack#