# Create a JavaFX DeskBand

Tags: java, javafx, taskbar

I would like to create a Desk Band Application in Windows 10 using JavaFX.
I saw this post [.NET Embedding application in windows-taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148372/net-embedding-application-in-windows-taskbar) and this is exactly what i want to do, but in JavaFX.

I'm searching everywhere but i don't find anything that explains how can i do it...

Someone can give me a hint from where to start?

I start looking about Desk Bands as said in the post, but it' too specific for C#.

Comment: JavaFX currently has no task bar support. You could conceivably use AWT, but it doesn't seem to make much sense to use Java, which is designed to be platform-independent, to write something you are specifically targeting to a particular platform. Surely it would be more sensible to use a Windows-specific technology for this.

Comment: Thanks, i know that's not the right thing to do, but do you think i could do something like a C# application deskband to show a JavaFX application, i don't have much knowledge on C#, and particularly, i don't like it very much. I think javafx is more customizable with css, i have more knowledge on it too.